# Confusion between covariant and partial derivatives

Tags: metric-spaces, vector-analysis, tensors

Let, we are in 1d cartesian space with metric $g_{xx} = x^2$. Let we have a vector $v = 1/x e_x$. Since the vector is designed to shrink its components as the basis grows - its total length will remain constant - meaning thar it will be parallel transported along X axis, and its covariant derivative will be zero. But what about its partial derivative (or just derivative, since its a 1d case)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Can you write a formula for the partial derivative in terms of $v$'s only component?

Comment: It seems to be the same as the one for the covariant derivative, including Christoffels, since the basis is changing. That's where I am getting confused.

Comment: Glad you mentioned Christoffel symbols, because $\color{red}{\nabla_xv_x}=\color{blue}{\partial_xv_x}+\frac12g^{xx}\partial_xg_{xx}v_x$. As you've noted, the red part is $0$; you want the blue part.

Comment: So the partial derivative takes only the component changes into account. Is that true even if it’s a polar system (but the space is flat)?